# D3 tree layout from json

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a d3 project to allow dynamic tree creation.

This creates the tree correctly, however if I save the tree as json and re-load it, then add some nodes, it messes up the tree structure completely.

The json structure looks ok, and I strip out attributes that d3 adds to the data:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(treeData,function( key, value) {
                    if( key == 'parent') { return value.name;}
                    else if( key == 'depth') { return undefined;}
                    else if( key == 'x') { return undefined;}
                    else if( key == 'y') { return undefined;}
                    else {return value;}
                    });
```

it looks like d3 is exiting the nodes starting from depth 0.

Please see fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z15825qu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
var node = select.data(nodes, function(d) 
                        { 
                            if(d.Type!=="e"){
                                d.ExpVal=function(){return CalcEV(d);}();
                            }
                            return d.id || (d.id = ++self.i);//this is the problem 
                        });
```

Make the Id generation random

```
var node = select.data(nodes, function(d) 
                        { 
                            if(d.Type!=="e"){
                                d.ExpVal=function(){return CalcEV(d);}();
                            }
                            return d.id || (d.id = parseInt(Math.random()*100)); //make the id generation random
                        });
```

**Reason:**

When you are drawing it for first time localStorage has no data stored so id generation is unique when you do *++self.i*.

Now in the case when localstorage has values and it gets rendered from there.
A node gets added, *++self.i*.  will generate ids of node already present(as it will start from 0). Thus everything goes awry since you have multiple nodes with same id.

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/q8w4nwk5/1/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! Although I think what I may do is add the id to the json so that it remains deterministic.